# AWS APIGateway Lambda Custom Authrozier principalId

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am looking at these blueprints: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/nodejs/index.js

What is the principalId for and how is it generated?

I see the code like this:

```
// this could be accomplished in a number of ways:
// 1. Call out to OAuth provider
// 2. Decode a JWT token inline
// 3. Lookup in a self-managed DB
var principalId = 'user|a1b2c3d4'
```

The questions I have are:

1. Is it unique per user? I have a dynamodb where the users table has a unique user Id.
2. How do I use it in lambda as an environment variable in the AWS lambda console?
3. What is the main purpose of it in the autnorizer?

Thanks for reading and responding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, please see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=703105
2. Based on the answers to the other 2 questions you probably don't want this to be an environment variable, unless I'm misinterpreting what you're asking.
3. See above forum post

   > The principalId is intended to represent the long term identifier for whatever entity is being authorized to make the API call.

Comment: I have a question about this. Can I use this token that returns from getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity as the principalId? It always comes back as the same token for the same user after login.

Comment: Another note: Is var principalId = event.authorizationToken; ? Just curious about this.